# Bundle.main.path returns nil

Tags: swift, path, null

I keep getting a nil path when I try to access a file in my project using the following code:

```
let path: String
if let pathOfFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "comfortJH", ofType: "csv")
{
    path = pathOfFile
}
let stream = InputStream(fileAtPath: path)
```

[I have checked my target memberships for the file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpA1e.png)

[I have also checked that it appears in "Copy Bundle Resources".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rQ9E.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Get rid of `path`. Move `let stream = ...` inside the `if let` and use `pathOfFile` instead of `path`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct target memberShip

[image]